# The device, \Device\Harddisk4\DR37, has a bad block

Tags: raid, hard-drive, hardware

I've received the error below and wondering if it's something I should be worried about? I've checked the RAID controller and all are functioning without errors.

Log Name:      System
Source:        disk
Date:          01/03/2013 17:55:23
Event ID:      7
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      TBHSERVER.tbh.local
Description:
The device, \Device\Harddisk4\DR37, has a bad block.
Event Xml:

Answer (score 1):

Bad blocks are a physical problem on the drive. Replace the drive ASAP. It appears this drive is in a server, is it part of a RAID array?

I'll just add, your drive isn't likely to burst into flames tomorrow, but I would prepare to replace it, especially if you don't have a spare in your array currently.

Comment: yeah its part of a RAID

Answer (score 1):

A bad block means that one of the blocks on your disk is unreadable and unwritable.  Sometimes it's an indication that a disk is starting to fail, but usually it doesn't mean anything in an of itself, other than the fact that you've lost whatever data was on it before it went bad.  I'd check the SMART data on your drive to make sure there's no impending failure getting ready to bite you, run a consistency check on your data to make sure the unreadable block isn't affecting your data or RAID redundancy, and then assuming you have things set up properly (backups and your RAID array has a hot spare), go back to whatever else is on the agenda.

Bad disk blocks happen, and as long as you've got everything else squared away, they're usually nothing to worry about.

Comment: No image of the server due to errors occurring during backup but we have backups of the server using backup exec.